# Why does my iPhone 4S go blank due to over heating?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 4S is just 2 weeks old and since the last week it enters this weird mode where the screen goes blank and I can't access the phone, but if someone tries to call me, it rings, proving that the phone isn't turned off.

The store guy said that it's happening because Im using the phone too much which is causing the phone to overheat and go on a sleep mode.

My phone goes on this wierd sleep mode atleast twice in a day! Even during the night!  What can I do?

Comment: If you can make it overheat - document the temperature and situation and show them proof that it's overheating under normal circumstances. Anyone can trigger overtemp by putting a phone in an oven or a hot car - just ask them what proof they need, and provide it. Also, ask Apple to document in writing what they are telling you so it can be about the facts and not so much what either side "said" - nail down the details and be nice (or at least pleasant) for best results.

Answer (score 1):

The store guy is telling you crap, there is no such thing as a sleep mode that would exhibit the symptoms you describe.  Demand an exchange.

Comment: I had an Apple Store guy indicate that it wasn't a problem, but I simply insisted (politely but firmly) that they replace it, and they did. Poof, problem solved.

Comment: Indeed, I should have said "Demand (politely) an exchange" :)

Comment: I would say if the store person only told the OP what was written, then that is crap. I suspect the technician at the store wrote up a case documenting what was reported, what was observed and ran some thorough diagnostics and probably recommended three things to try to rule out software. I don't think we're getting even 1/5 of the story here. Devices that overheat under normal use get exchanged under warranty.

Comment: Yes, @bmike, in theory. However, my girlfriend got her 4S first and had overheating problems. They ran diagnostics, the whole bit, wiped and restored, etc., and said they wouldn't replace it. Off she went and the phone began overheating again the same day. Took it back, same rigamarole. On her third visit she insisted they replace it and they did, and poof, problem solved. When I got mine and it began overheating, I took it in, they went through the rigamarole, and tried to send me off. I insisted instead, and got a replacement. They're not as eager to replace as you'd think.

Comment: I agree not everyone gets perfect service, but I would love to see the diagnostic notes as to why visit 2 the employee didn't offer an exchange. It seems they owed you a darn good reason why a recently restored phone would overheat the same day as it was determined that the first step in isolating the issue would be to restore it. I would problably escalate (speak to a manager) if I was in that situation. That being said, I also can overheat any phone in a hot car, controlled environment by stressing the CPU/GPU. You need to measure the ambient temp to know if the device is faulty...